# Get related fields from Salesforce objects using Amazon Appflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-appflow

I'm trying to create a flow between Salesforce and Amazon S3 in order to get ready-to-use reports. For that purpose, I need to get related fields of the objects I'm importing. For example, I have an Invoice object which relates to a Contract (one contract may have multiple invoices), and in my report, I would need to get an external id of the contract.

Using SOQL and the Bulk API, I can retrieve this field using the following query: `SELECT ID_Contract__r.External_ID__c FROM Invoice__c`, therefore it is possible to get related fields using this API (which can be selected to be used by Appflow). Also, after asking to Amazon Q, it says that it's possible to do this mapping (although I'm not sure if it is an hallucination):

[image]

However, in the Appflow console, I can't see any option that allows me to get those related fields. Could you please tell me how can I retrieve them? And if it is not possible, could you explain me why, as the Salesforce API does allow it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a ticket with AWS Support, they confirmed me that getting related fields was not possible at the moment. I think it's a pity and it would be a great feature to have in Appflow, but I guess we will have to wait for now.